# Showing how many completed tasks VS how many tasks there are in a JS ToDo list

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been making a really simple ToDo list using HTML, JS and CSS and the only thing left is to show the user how many tasks there are and how many are completed. E.g. if there is 3 completed ones and 7 tasks in all, it should output 3/7. I've been trying to do this with some eventlisteners and stuff, but can't get it to work... How can I do this using the ouput element in the HTML and JS?

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button')
var ul = document.getElementById('todo')
var output = document.getElementsByName('result')


button.addEventListener("click", addTask);
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
})

function addTask() {
  var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT")
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  var label = document.createElement("LABEL");
  var li = document.createElement("LI");
  var task = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('task').value);
  label.appendChild(task)
  li.appendChild(label)
  li.insertBefore(checkbox, li.childNodes[0])
  ul.appendChild(li)

  var date = new Date()
  tasks.push({
    text: document.getElementById('task').value,
    date: date
  })
}

var tasks = []
console.log(tasks)
```

```css
#todo {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>To-do list</h1>
  </header>

  <form class="" action="" method="">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Add task" id="button">
    <input type="text" name="input" id="task" autofocus>
    <output name="result"></output>
    <ul id="todo"></ul>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach adds two elements to show completed todos and the total count.  Likewise, binds the event `change` to every newly created checkbox to capture when the user clicks on them.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button')
var ul = document.getElementById('todo')
var output = document.getElementsByName('result')
var total = document.getElementById('total')
var completed = document.getElementById('completed')

button.addEventListener("click", addTask);
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

function addTask() {
  var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  
  // Add one more todo in total count.
  total.textContent = +total.textContent + 1;
  
  //Thrigger the completed event
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    if (this.checked) completed.textContent = +completed.textContent + 1;
    else completed.textContent = +completed.textContent - 1;
  });
  
  var label = document.createElement("LABEL");
  var li = document.createElement("LI");
  var task = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('task').value);
  label.appendChild(task)
  li.appendChild(label)
  li.insertBefore(checkbox, li.childNodes[0])
  ul.appendChild(li)

  var date = new Date()
  tasks.push({
    text: document.getElementById('task').value,
    date: date
  });
}

var tasks = []
console.log(tasks)
```

```css
#todo {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>To-do list</h1>
  </header>

  <form class="" action="" method="">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Add task" id="button">
    <input type="text" name="input" id="task" autofocus>
    <output name="result"></output>
    <p>My completed todos: <span id='completed'>0</span> / <span id='total'>0</span> </p>
    <ul id="todo"></ul>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its not working is because you put it inside a form. Forms should be used only when you want to submit a POST or PUT request to the server running the website. When the button of "submit" is pressed the browser refreshes the page because it sent a POST request to the server, and it responded (most likely with a 404 - Not Found). So firstly, you have to remove the form.

Second, I advise you strongly to use jQuery instead of using regular DOM manipulation methods. It is way faster, more scalable and not to mention easier to read and write. Here is a Plunker with your code that I adapted slightly to make it work.You can view it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/fynjMcctr7na57e05dK7?p=preview).

```
var tasks = []

var button = $('#button')
var ul = $('#todo')
var output = $('#result')

button.click(function() {
  addTask();
});

function addTask() {
  var li = $('<li/>');

  var checkbox = $('<input/>')
    .attr('type', 'checkbox');

  var taskText = $('#task').val();
  var label = $('<label/>')
    .html(taskText);

  li.append(checkbox);
  li.append(label);

  ul.append(li);

  var now = new Date()
  tasks.push({
    text: taskText,
    date: now
  });
  console.log(tasks);
```

### }

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>To-do list</h1>
  </header>

  <div>
    <button name="button" value="Add task" id="button">Add task</button>
    <input type="text" name="input" id="task" autofocus>
    <output name="result"></output>
    <ul id="todo"></ul>
  </div>

  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```